# Intall MCrypt extension in nginx server with PHP 7

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, php-7, ubuntu-server

I got a server with Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed nginx and PHP 7 with fpm. I need to install MCrypt extension but I cannot find how to do it, I found some information for PHP 5.6 and I'm not sure if the process is the same. How can I do it?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it has been abandonware for nearly a decade now. It has therefore been deprecated and will be removed from the core and into PECL in PHP 7.2. It does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding bugs dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @zaph to install phpmyadmin it ask to have installed MCrypt, and also the laravel projects to be excuted :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to download the latest version of [phpmyadmin 4.6.6](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/files/4.6.6/)

> - Fixes for PHP 7.1
> - Problems with MySQL servers running with `lower_case_names=2`
> - Fixes for several PHP notices/warnings being shown

they've fixed this [bug](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12800)

by the way , to install [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php) in unbutu for PHP 7:

`apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt`

which again is **DEPRECATED** in *PHP 7.1.x*

Warning

> This extension has been deprecated as of PHP 7.1.0 and moved to PECL
>   as of PHP 7.2.0.